# Hadoop Data Blocks and Data Content

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, block

Hadoop breaks up the content of the input data into blocks without regard to the content.
As a post described:

> HDFS has no idea (and doesn’t care) what’s stored inside the file, so raw files are not split in accordance with rules that we humans would understand. Humans, for example, would want record boundaries — the lines showing where a record begins and ends — to be respected.

The part I am unclear is that if the data is split based only on the data size without regards to the content, then would there not be implication on the accuracy of queries performed later? For instance, an often sited example of list of cities and daily temperatures. could a city be in one block and its temperature somewhere else, how then a map operation correctly queries the info. There seems to be something fundamental about blocks and MR queries that I am missing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> could a city be in one block and its temperature somewhere else

That is entirely possible, yes. In this instance, the record boundary crosses two blocks, and both are gathered.

Accuracy is not lost, but performance is, sure, in terms of Disk and network IO. When the end of a block is detected without reaching an InputSplit, then the next block is read. Even if this split  is within the first few bytes of that following block, it's byte stream is still processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lets get into basics of ext FileSystem(forget HDFS for timebeing). 
 1. In your Hardisk data is stored in form of track and sectors.  Now when a file is stored its not necessary the complete record will be saved in the same block(4kb) and it can span across blocks . 
 2. The Process which is reading the files, reads the block and find the record boundary (Record is a logical entity). A record is a logical entity
 3. The file saved into Hardisk as bytes has no understanding of record or file format. File format and records are logical entities. 


Apply the same logic on HDFS. 
 1. The block size is 128MB. 
 2. Just like ext filesystem HDFS has no clue of the record boundaries. 
 3. What Mappers do is logically find the record boundaries by 
    a. The mapper which reads fileOffset 0 starts reading from start of file, till it finds \n.
    b. All mapper which don't read a file from offset 0 will skip the bytes till they reach \n and then continue reading. The sequences of bytes till newline is ommited. Now this byte sequence can be a complete record or partial record and is consumed by other mapper.  
    c. Mappers will read the block they are supposed to and continue reading till they find \n which is present in other block and not on the block which is local to them.
    d. Except first mapper all other mapper read the block local to them and byte sequence from other block till they find \n.
```

Answer (score 0):

See Ali,

the data block were decided by hadoop hdfs gateway in stored procedure and this will based on the hadoop version 1.x or 2.x and depends on size of the file too, which you are placing from the local to hadoop gateway and later after -put command, the hadoop gateway splits the file blocks and stores to your data node directory `/data/dfs/data/current/` (if you are running on single node then it is inside your hadoop directory) in form of blk_`<job_process_id>` and meta data about the blk_ with same job_id name and with .meta extension.

Size of data blocks in Hadoop 1 is 64 mb and in Hadoop 2 it increased to 128 mb block size and thereafter depending on file size it split the block as per I said earlier, so there is no tool to control this thing in hadoop hdfs, if anything, please let me know!

In Hadoop 1, We put simply a file in cluster like below said, if file size is 100 mb then what -

```
bin/hadoop fs -put <full-path of the input file till ext> </user/datanode/(target-dir)>
```

Hadoop 1 gateway will divide the file in two(64 mb & 36 mb) blocks and Hadoop 2 make it simply one block and sequentially replicates those blocks as per your configuration.

if you are placing a jar using hadoop for map reduce jobs then there you can set `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` method inside you java Mapper-Reducer class to 1 and later after testing export a jar for mr job like below.

```
//Setting the Results to Single Target File in Java File inside main method
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

and later run the hadoop fs script like :

```
bin/hadoop jar <full class path of your jar file> <full class path of Main class inside jar> <input directory or file path> <give the output target directory>
```

If you are using sqoop to import the data from rdbms engines then there you can use the "-m 1" to set the single file result but it varies from your question.

Hope, my answer will give a glance to you on the issue, thanks.